# Reorganização de array de dados para exibição

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou criando uma aplicação usando `AngularJs` e `skeleton`, tenho o layout montado, agora estou na parte de deixá-lo dinâmico, mas estou enfrentando um probleminha básico. Tenho o seguinte array que vem do back-end:

```
[
    0 => [
        'title'         => 'Um titulo aqui',
        'slug'          => 'Aqui-o-slug',
        'categoria_id'  => 17
    ],
    1 => [
        'title'         => 'Um titulo aqui',
        'slug'          => 'Aqui-o-slug',
        'categoria_id'  => 12
    ],
    2 => [
        'title'         => 'Um titulo aqui',
        'slug'          => 'Aqui-o-slug',
        'categoria_id'  => 4
    ]
]
```

O layout comporta 4 elementos do array, a cada 4 eu tenho que colocar dentro de um novo "row" para não quebrar o layout. O que eu quero saber é qual forma eu poderia fazer isso, quais funções e etc, pretendo deixar o código o mais simples possível.

Obs: Uso `php` no back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No angular, existe a propriedade `ng-repeat` que irá repetir um bloco de código para cada objeto de sua array. Veja um exemplo:

```
<li ng-repeat="dados in $scope.minhaArray">{{dados.categoria_id}} - {{dados.title}}</li>
```

Que iria gerar o seguinte html:

```
<li>17 - Um título aqui</li>
<li>12 - Um título aqui</li>
<li>4 - Um título aqui</li>
```

O seu problema é que você precisa repetir dentro de um `row` 4 objetos da array, mas o `ng-repeat` não faz isso. Acredito que você possua 2 soluções:

- Mudar o seu layout; Mais simples e menos propício a erros.
- Mudar sua array; mais 'complexo' e mais propício a erros.

A mudança de layout não tem muito o que falar, teria que adaptar de modo que se enquadre em suas necessidades e que seja possível usar o `ng-repeat`.

A mudança de array seria mais complexa. Você precisaria gerar uma array dentro de array, onde cada array-filho contenha apenas 4 objetos, ficando uma array +- assim:

```
[
    {data1: [
        {categoria_id: 1, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 2, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 3, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 4, title: 'um titulo aqui'}
           ]
    },
    {data2: [
        {categoria_id: 5, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 6, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 7, title: 'um titulo aqui'},
        {categoria_id: 8, title: 'um titulo aqui'}
           ]
    },
    {data3: ...etc...
]
```

Assim você poderia ter um html deste modo:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="data in $scope.minhaLista">
    <div class="bloco" ng-repeat="dados in data">
        {{dados.categoria_id}} - {{dados.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```